# Best way to present a pushgateway metric in Grafana

Tags: prometheus

I am new to Prometheus.
I wrote a bash script that retuns either "1" or "0", and using pushgateway created a metric in prometheus for it.

In pushgatway metrics UI I can see the meteic's value as expected (or so I think):

```
# TYPE pg_bck untyped
pg_bck{instance="11.98.8.14",job="pg_bck"} 0
```

In Grafana however, if I pick "stats" or "gauge" visualization the graph, or gauge, shows a number with a decimal point (e.g: 0.245)

What is the correct way to show the value as either 1 or 0 in Grafana ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the value is supposed to increase/decrease, I think it is better to expose it as a "gauge".

https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge

Furthermore, you probably want to check the "Instant" setting in the grafana query to get the last value.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.

Haven't checked your suggestion as seems like choosing for the pannel calulation "last" (as appraenlty the default alucaltion is the avarage) solved the problem.